# Notice error while counting number occurrences

Tags: php, php-gd, e-notices

I'm creating a simple .php script that

1. Generates an array with random numbers (let's say 1000 integers)
2. Outputs an image, where it displays all these numbers' arrangement on a scale from 0 to the largest number drawn

The output is an image (with given width), this is what I got:

[image: image output example]

As you can see, at some points the *bars* are higher. It's because the image usually isn't wide enough to present all the numbers, so if there are more numbers laying on one pixel, then the bar is going higher.

**The problem:** Sometimes this script works well, but occasionally I get numerous Notice errors:

> **Notice:** Undefined offset: **398** in /.../index.php on line **61**
>
> **Notice:** Undefined offset: **125** in /.../index.php on line **61**
>
> **Notice:** Undefined offset: **192** in /.../index.php on line **61** ...

The script is below, some explanations:

- Line 61 marked red (below)
- function toScale() returns intval( number / maxNumber * scaleWidth )
- inb4 unnecessary double declaration of $counts[num]=0, that's what I've done trying to solve the problem, it doesn't seem to change anything
- *$counts* isn't used anywhere else in between these two parts
- the number of *Notice* errors is never equal to the total numbers count, it's either a few or none of these.

[image: code screenshot]

**Update:** As [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) mentioned, the second loop from my code can be replaced with

```
$max = max($data); $counts = array_count_values(array_map('toScale', $data));
```

It looks like just code simplification, but somehow this solves the problem. Why?

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for code formatting help.

Comment: Your second loop can be replaced with `$max = max($data); $counts = array_count_values(array_map('toScale', $data));`

Comment: Sorry for putting my code into an image, I got some errors trying to format it properly, never happened before. Barmar's idea works and solves the problem! But still, why the above code does not work?

Comment: Do you modify `$data` between the two loops?

Comment: My comment shouldn't fix anything, it just simplifies the code.

Comment: That's what I thought. But somehow it does fix it. My mind is blown now

Comment: Yeah, I realized that as well. See my answer for the reason.

Comment: How is maxNumber in toScale() determined? If it uses the global $max, it will change as you fill up the $counts array resulting in inconsistent behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're scaling your numbers differently in the two loops.

In the first loop, you're updating `$max` each time through the loop, and then calling `toScale(data[$x])`. Since `toScale()` depends on `$max`, some numbers will be scaled to a different maximum.

In the second loop, everything is scaled to the final maximum. So for the same values of `$data[$a]` you'll get a different `toScale($data[$a])` this time.

You need to calculate the maximum of all the numbers before any calls to `toScale`. One way of doing this is by calculating the maximum in the loop that's generating all the random numbers:

```
$max = 0;
for ($a = 0; $a < $num; $a++) {
    $rand = rand();
    if ($rand > $max) {
        $max = $rand;
    }
    $data[] = $rand;
}
```

Or you can do it using a built-in function:

```
$max = max($data);
$counts = array_count_values(array_map('toScale', $data));
```